# urllib2 urlopen will be block in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, urllib2

I want make use of multiprocessing to speed report generator for every company

following is test script:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import os, time, random, json, urllib, urllib2, uuid

def generate_report(url, cookie, company_id, period, remark):
    try:
        start = time.time()
        print('Run task %s (%s)... at: %s \n' % (company_id, os.getpid(), start))

        values = {
            'companies': json.dumps([company_id]),
            'month_year': period,
            'remark': remark
        }

        data = urllib.urlencode(values)

        headers = {
            'Cookie': cookie
        }
        url = "%s?pid=%s&uuid=%s" % (url, os.getpid(), uuid.uuid4().get_hex())
        request = urllib2.Request(url, data, headers)
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        content = response.read()
        end = time.time()
        print 'Task %s runs %0.2f seconds, end at: %s \n' % (company_id, (end - start), end)
        return content
    except Exception as exc:
        return exc.message

if __name__=='__main__':
    print 'Parent process %s.\n' % os.getpid()
    p = Pool()

    url = 'http://localhost/fee_calculate/generate-single'
    cookie = 'xxx'
    company_ids = [17,15,21,19]
    period = '2017-08'
    remark = 'test add remark from python script'

    results = [p.apply_async(generate_report, args=(url,cookie,company_id,period,remark)) for company_id in company_ids]
    for r in results:
        print(r.get())
```

but I get the result as following:

```
Run task 17 (15952)... at: 1506568581.98
Run task 15 (17192)... at: 1506568581.99
Run task 21 (18116)... at: 1506568582.01
Run task 19 (1708)... at: 1506568582.05

Task 17 runs 13.50 seconds, end at: 1506568595.48

{"success":true,"info":"Successed!"}
Task 15 runs 23.60 seconds, end at: 1506568605.59

{"success":true,"info":"Successed!"}
Task 21 runs 34.35 seconds, end at: 1506568616.36

{"success":true,"info":"Successed!"}
Task 19 runs 44.38 seconds, end at: 1506568626.44

{"success":true,"info":"Successed!"}
```

it seems the urllib2.urlopen(request) has been blocked, the request not been sent parallelly, but orderly.

In order to test multiprocessing, the script fee_calculate/generate-single only has following important code:

```
sleep(10)
```

please give me advice, thanks.

PS:
Platform: windows10, python2.7, 4 CPU

Comment: How many CPU cores does your machine have? Try running os.cpu_count() and see what the result is.

Comment: Are you sure, that time should be less? Probably report generating take all time? You can try to use `async` instead `multiprocessing`

Comment: @DBrowne there are four cpu,  so, I just fork 4 subprocess like this: company_ids = [17,15,21,19]

Comment: @AndMar  the report generating just sleep 10 seconds for test.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a multiprocessing issue. Multiprocessing is working as it should which you can see by observing that all of the tasks are starting at approximately the same time.

The task execution time is almost entirely dictated by the response time of your local endpoint at `http://localhost/fee_calculate/generate-single`. How are you running this server? If you observe the execution times for each of the reports you will notice that they are increasing in steps of ~10 seconds, which is your artificially imposed processing delay on the server side (`sleep(10)`).

I suspect that your local server is only single-threaded, and so can only handle one request at a time. This means that each request must be completed before the next one is processed, so when you make multiple concurrent requests like this you don't actually get any decrease in processing time.

Comment: At the very beginning, I suspect local server is only single-threaed too. so I checked XAMPP mpm_winnt_module, and open http://localhost/fee_calculate/generate-single in multiple tabs  on Firefox . I checked all response header, them almost return at the same time, only have 1 ~ 2 second gap

Comment: What happens when you open multiple tabs in Firefox at the same time? Do all of them complete after 10 seconds? Or do they take longer than that?

Comment: I have fixed this bug. Yes, it's not multiprocessing  issue. I think the bug is same cookie lead to waiting session lock.  application was built on zend_framework.  thanks very much.